# Animation Listener Crashes Application

Tags: android, eclipse, listener

Hi Im working through the Samms book. My App works fine up until I inserted the following code straight from the book :

```
TextView logo2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewBottomTitle);
        Animation fade2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in2);
        logo2.startAnimation(fade2);
        fade2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) { startActivity(new Intent(QuizSplashActivity.this,
            QuizMenuActivity.class)); QuizSplashActivity.this.finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

The Splash screen loads the animation plays and finishes but when the event should fire it crashes and says

Comment: Sorry, the Message must have gotten deleted : The Application "App Name" has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.

Comment: You should run it in debug mode and post the Exception

Comment: Houcine, thanks that did it!!! Is there a way to say you answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Houcine.

"add the stack trace of your exception , and work on your accept rate. NB : may be your activity QuizMenuActivity is not declared on your manifest file – Houcine 23 hours ago"